# FTP link to PDF not downloading

Tags: google-chrome, ftp

Within my companies Intranet, we have FTP links to certain files.  This morning, a few of my PCs stopped downloading the files and instead prompted me to open them with IE (I was using Chrome).  The versions of Chrome on each PC are updated to the most recent (Version 87.0.4280.66).  I changed the default app for opening FTP files to Chrome, which only alleviated the IE message, but still refuses to download.  I have compared settings with a few PCs that are working as intended and cannot find a difference that would cause this.  Is there perhaps something I am overlooking?  How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FTP support in Chrome is deprecated](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/6246151319715840).

> The current FTP implementation in Google Chrome has no support for
> encrypted connections (FTPS), nor proxies. Usage of FTP in the browser
> is sufficiently low that it is no longer viable to invest in improving
> the existing FTP client. In addition more capable FTP clients are
> available on all affected platforms.

It is disabled by default in Chrome 87.

It will be removed completely in Chrome 88.

Comment: I did come across that.  I guess I'm still confused as to why the majority of my PCs can still access it, but a few cannot?  They are all on the same version, as I mentioned, which should be the newest version.